# Find the largest 2 values and return either the row number or name in another column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

[Here is an example of my spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8uYe.png)

The true spreadsheet has around 20 rows of information per sheet. I'd like to find the top two scores and then return either the name of the person the score belongs to (preferable) OR return the number of the row that score belongs in.

Comment: you need the largest of the total or for each month

Comment: How do you want to handle duplicates? What if there is a tie at number 1 itself, do you want to return both as number 1?

Answer (score 1):

The formula looks for duplicate Maximum that is why I prefer to find the Row and from this write the First and Last Name

`=MATCH(MAX($I$3:$I$6),$I$3:$I$6,0)+2`
Result the row number For the Largest (Total)
$I$3:$I$6 the Total column change it to correspond to your Data
If this is in K3 write in L3 write for the Name:

`=INDEX($A$3:$A$6,K3-2,1)&" "&INDEX($B$3:$B$6,K3-2,1)`
First and Last Name
For the second Largest (if duplicate maximum it will be the Maximum in another row, or the second largest in case of non duplicate maximum)

`=IF(COUNTIF($I$3:$I$6,MAX($I$3:$I$6))>1,MAX((--($I$3:I6=MAX($I$3:$I$6)))*ROW($I$3:$I$6)),MATCH(LARGE($I$3:$I$6,2),$I$3:$I$6,0)+2)`
Press at the same time `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `Enter`
It will count the Max, if the count >1 Max(row) for values=Max
and Match(Large(,2)) in case count =1

The name will be if the above formula is in K4, in L4:

`=INDEX($A$3:$A$6,K4-2,1)&" "&INDEX($B$3:$B$6,K4-2,1)`
First and Last Name

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For your data, in **K1** enter:

```
=MATCH(LARGE(J:J,ROW()),J:J,0)
```

and copy down:

[image]

As you see, this gives the rows for John Cabal and Darth Vader.

*This assumes that the values have no ties.*